# Adjoints for the functor ${\bf Top}\to {\bf Conv}$

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, adjoint-functors

Let $X$ be a set and let $\Phi(X)$ denote the collection of [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)) on $X$. For $x\in X$ we denote by $P_x$ the filter $P_x=\{A\subseteq X:x\in A\}$. A *convergence space* is a pair $(X,\to)$, where $X$ is a set, and $\to$ is a subset of $\Phi(X)\times X$ with the following properties:

1. $P_x \to x$ for all $x\in X$ (we write ${\cal F}\to x$ instead of $({\cal F},x)\in \to$), and
2. If ${\cal F}\subseteq {\cal G}\in \Phi(X)$ and ${\cal F}\to x$, then ${\cal G}\to x$.

If $(X,\to_X)$ and $(Y,\to_Y)$ are convergence spaces, then $f: X\to Y$ is said to be *continuous* if ${\cal F}\in \Phi(X), x\in X$ and ${\cal F}\to_X x$ imply $f({\cal F}) \to_Y f(x)$, where $f({\cal F})$ is the [image filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Functions_on_topological_spaces) of ${\cal F}$.

The category ${\bf Conv}$ consists of convergence spaces with continous maps between them. There is a functor ${\bf Top}\to {\bf Conv}$ constructed in the following way:

- Objects: $(X,\tau)$ maps to $(X,\to_\tau)$ where ${\cal F} \to_\tau x$ if and only if ${\cal F} \supseteq {\cal N}_x$, where ${\cal N}_x$ is the neighborhood filter of $x$ in $(X,\tau)$.
- Maps: It is easy to see that a continous map in the topological sense is continuous in the convergence space sense, so the functor is the identity on the morphisms.

**Question.** Does this functor have an adjoint going back from ${\bf Conv}$ to ${\bf Top}$?

---

**Note.** Many topological properties can be transferred to convergence spaces. For instance, a convergence space $(X,\to)$ is *compact* if for every ultrafilter ${\cal U}\in \Phi(X)$ there is $x\in X$ such that ${\cal U}\to x$. Also, [Tychonoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem) can be proved for compact convergence spaces. Moreover, a convergence space is said to be $T_2$ if ${\cal F}\to x$ and ${\cal F} \to y$ imply $x=y$.

Comment: In a comment to a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/265596/41291) Todd Trimble gave a link to the nLab entry on [relational $\beta$-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relational+beta-module) which I think answers much of this question

Comment: I don't see how to construct the functor from Conv to Top...

Comment: It is at that nLab page, just before Proposition 2.1: $U$ is open iff for any $\mathcal F\to x$ with $\mathcal F$ and ultrafilter, $x\in U$ implies $U\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: Section 5 of: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space
is also relevant.

Comment: Oh I see - can you put this as an answer so we can close this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At @DominicvanderZypen's [request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283376/adjoints-for-the-functor-bf-top-to-bf-conv#comment699664_283376), here is
@მამუკა-ჯიბლაძე's answer from the comments [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283376/adjoints-for-the-functor-bf-top-to-bf-conv#comment699473_283376) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283376/adjoints-for-the-functor-bf-top-to-bf-conv#comment699478_283376) (marked as CW to avoid reputation):

> In a comment to a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/265596) Todd Trimble gave a link to the nLab entry on [relational $\beta$-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relational+beta-module) which I think answers much of this question.
>
> It [the construction of the functor $\mathbf{Conv} \to \mathbf{Top}$] is at that nLab page, just [before Proposition 2.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relational+beta-module#bridge_to_a_concrete_description): $U$ is open iff for any $\mathcal F \to x$ with $\mathcal F$ an ultrafilter, $x \in U$ implies $U \in \mathcal F$.